# Disabled Content Links with Fullpage.js and scrolloverflow.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and scrolloverflow.js in one of my projects.
After using the option **"scrollOverflow : true"**, the content links in any affected section become disabled.

This is my own Function to call Fullpage:

```
    jQuery('#fullpage-scroll').fullpage({
        keyboardScrolling : true,
        navigation : true,
        scrollOverflow : true 
    });
```

This is the Code for an affected section after loading Fullpage.js and Scrolloverflow.js:

```
<section id="marketing-tools" class="section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" style="height: 886px;">
<div style="height:886px;" class="fp-tableCell">
    <div class="fp-scrollable" style="height: 886px;">
        <div class="fp-scroller" style="transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, -359px) translateZ(0px);">
            <div class="marketing-bg">
                <div class="headerimage-teaserbox center" id="c210">
                    <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">
                        <div data-csc-cols="2" data-csc-images="1" class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
                            <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last"><img width="1500" height="1003" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/header/Start_audience-868074_1920_pixabay.jpg">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="marketing-content">

                <div class="csc-default" id="c1335">
                    <h2>Auf den Überblick kommt es an</h2>
                    <h3>E-Mail Newsletter | Eventmarketing | Online Umfragen&nbsp;</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="csc-default" id="c213">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="csc-default" id="c214">
                            <div class="row col3 col3-33">
                                <div class="col col-1" style="height: 513px;">
                                    <div class="cirlce-image small" id="c215">
                                        <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">
                                            <div data-csc-cols="2" data-csc-images="1" class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
                                                <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last">
                                                    <a href="e_mail_marketing/"><img width="438" height="438" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/layoutbilder/Iconbilder/E_Mail_Marketing.png"></a>
                                                </figure>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="csc-default" id="c218">
                                        <h3>E-Mail Marketing</h3>
                                        <p class="bodytext">
                                            Vom E-Mail Newsletter bis zu vollautomatischen Kampagnen mit Auswertungen in Echtzeit.
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="bodytext">
                                            eyepin ist einfach zu bedienen, bietet hohe Effizienz und gibt Ihrer Marke einen perfekten Auftritt.&nbsp;
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="e_mail_marketing/" class="more-link-invisible"><img width="438" height="438" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/layoutbilder/Iconbilder/E_Mail_Marketing.png"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-2" style="height: 513px;">
                                    <div class="cirlce-image small" id="c216">
                                        <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">
                                            <div data-csc-cols="2" data-csc-images="1" class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
                                                <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last">
                                                    <a href="event-marketing/"><img width="438" height="438" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/layoutbilder/Iconbilder/Event.png"></a>
                                                </figure>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="csc-default" id="c219">
                                        <h3>Eventmarketing</h3>
                                        <p class="bodytext">
                                            Veranstaltungen einfach online organisieren inklusive Event Website, Einladungsmanagement und Gästeliste.
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="bodytext">
                                            Mit eyepin bieten Sie Ihren Gästen den nötigen Komfort schon im Vorfeld der Veranstaltung.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="event-marketing/" class="more-link-invisible"><img width="438" height="438" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/layoutbilder/Iconbilder/Event.png"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-3" style="height: 513px;">
                                    <div class="cirlce-image small" id="c217">
                                        <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">
                                            <div data-csc-cols="2" data-csc-images="1" class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
                                                <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last">
                                                    <a href="marketing-suite/"><img width="439" height="438" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/layoutbilder/Iconbilder/MarketingSuite.png"></a>
                                                </figure>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="csc-default" id="c220">
                                        <h3>Marketing Suite</h3>
                                        <p class="bodytext">
                                            Sieben auf einen Streich: Die Marketing Suite bietet sieben Softwarelösungen in einer Marketing Suite.
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="bodytext">
                                            Newsletter | Eventmanagement | Online Umfragen | Landingpages | SMS/WhatsApp | Gewinnspiele | Social Media
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="marketing-suite/" class="more-link-invisible"><img width="439" height="438" alt="" src="fileadmin/user_upload/layoutbilder/Iconbilder/MarketingSuite.png"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="invisible">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; width: 7px; bottom: 2px; top: 2px; right: 1px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none;" class="iScrollVerticalScrollbar iScrollLoneScrollbar">
            <div style="box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); border-radius: 3px; width: 100%; transition-duration: 0ms; display: block; height: 620px; transform: translate(0px, 255px) translateZ(0px); transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1);" class="iScrollIndicator"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The Bug is affecting this [site](http://www2016.eyepin.com). The Links are around the boxes with the circle images.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known bug in scrolloverflow.js which is a fork of iScroll.js. See the topic [in their github forum](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/783).

You can also follow it in [fullpage.js forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2117).

The best solution so far is to detect whether the user is accessing through a touch device or not and turn `click:true` or `click:false` in scrolloverflow options as suggested in [this post](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2035#issuecomment-224549092).

Comment: Thanks for your response Alvaro, it works great now!

Comment: Solved in the `dev` version of fullpage.js in 2.8.2

Comment: Thanks for the information Alvaro, this will come in handy. Let the good work flowin!!

Answer (score 0):

Please display a web link to your project or code snippet so we can take a look.
Something is definitely blocking functionality from plugins that you are using.

Comment: Hi David, I checked your link and saw that all a tags do not have href displayed on "/". You can see this if you use developer tool, click F12 and click on img or element in your website. Check your html code, if there is a link then try commenting out plugin links in your html and see if it will work then. If all of this will not help then I recommend posting code snippets of html, css here.

Comment: hi, the links work if i set scrollOverflow : false, I've put some code in the description.